# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block(#151) at 0x00DB4E70

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management

I have implemented a List for my class Word, and have HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED, when program trying to delete my List. It goes into loop in destructor and delete first element, then when he goes second time, and trying to destroy "new" head I get Heap Corruption Error. I don't understand why it's going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Word.h:**

```
#include <cstring>
class Word
{
protected:
  char* word;
  char* type;
public:
  Word();
  Word(char );
  Word(char *);
  Word(char *, int);
  Word(const Word&);

  Word& operator=(const Word &);

  void setWord(char);
  void setWord(char *);
  void setWord(char*, int);

  void setType(char);
  void setType(char*);
  void setType(char*, int);

  ~Word();
};
```

**WordList.h:**

```
#include "Word.h"
#include <cstdlib>

class WordList
{
public:
 struct Node
 {
    Word data;
    Node  *next, *prev;
    //~Node();
 };
 Node *head;
 Node *tail;
 WordList();
 ~WordList();
 void add(Word &d);

};
```

**WordList.cpp:**

```
#include "WordList.h"


WordList::WordList(void)
{
head = nullptr;
tail = nullptr;
}

WordList::~WordList(void)
{
   while(head != nullptr)
   {
    Node *n = head->prev;
    delete head;
    head = n;
   }
}

void WordList::add(Word &d)
{
  Node *n = new Node;
  n->data = d;   // I overload =, and it copies information from d to data
  n->next = head; 
  if (head!=nullptr)
    head->prev = n;
  if(head == nullptr){
    head = n;
    tail = head;
  } else 
    head = n;
}
```

Comment: Try running it under the Application Verifier - you might hit a breakpoint when the corruption occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the destructor

```
 Node *n = head->prev;
```

needs to be

```
 Node *n = head->next;
```

If you'll follow you add method, you'll see that you never set `n` with a `prev` value, thus `head->prev` has the same value that `n->prev` had, which you've never set (to null), leaving `head->prev` with a junk value, deleting that address won't be pretty.

Comment: Oh it has one; Take a closer look a how a new node is added. Specifically pay attention to the *lack* of nullifying the `prev` pointer of a new node. IOW, it is indeterminate and therefore subject to spawn sewer monkeys.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are correct of course. My terminology was not clear enough, I'll edit.

Comment: A problem that can be easily rectified by having a constructor for class `Node`, something like : `Node(const Word& val) : data(val), next(), prev() {}`

Comment: And +1 on the pickup for using prev instead of next in the first place, btw.